# How to configure JAX-RS Client in order to make calls concurrently

Tags: java, http, jax-rs, wildfly

My webapp is accessed via http and makes itself http-calls. For that I use jaxrs-client. Since [Client](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html) is said to be an expensive resource, it is initialized once and reused within requests.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget webTarget = client.target(baseUri).path(...);
```

During requests an http-call is made like this:

```
Builder request = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
Response response = request.post(...);
try {
    // evaluate response
}
finally {
    response.close();
}
```

So everything works fine, as long as the webapp is deployed on TomEE or no parallelism takes place.
But when the code gets executed concurrently within Wildfly, then it fails with

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
  at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:162)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:144)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
```

The error is generated by Wildfly, apparently using apache-httpclient as part of its JAXRS implementation provider.

Asking google, one gets hints recommending settings for REST-EASY or apache-httpclient (pool size or specific HttpClientConnectionManager).
But my application has no dependency to one of them. It merely depends on `javax:javaee-api:7.0`

My question: Is there a vendor-independent way to configure `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` being able to make calls concurrently?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is..no. Here's the long answer:

Your code has a direct dependency on the jax-rs api (interfaces) defined in javaee-api. You deploy the code into wildfly, whose runtime provides Rest-Easy as a particular implementation of JAX-RS.  Wildfly's dependency management/class loading takes care of loading Rest-Easy's concrete implementation of the jax-rs api.

Rest-Easy makes use of the apache http client (the apache-http client is **not** an implementation of the jax-rs api, Rest Easy is) as the underlying http client. Without configuration, the apache-http client will run with BasicClientConnManager as the default. To handle concurrent requests you'll need explicitly configure a  multithreaded connection manager - see the apache http-client documentation [http-client documentation](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) for details - or let me know if you'd like an example.